# How to add check constraint on a column in table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

```
ALTER TABLE Student ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_Student_ID_LENGTH CHECK (LEN([ID]) between 12 and 14);


SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'CHK_Student_ID_LENGTH';


alter table Student drop constraint CHK_Student_ID_LENGTH;
```

I tried to add check constraint using the first statement. It gave me the below error.

> [23000][547] The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CHK_Student_ID_LENGTH". The conflict occurred in database, table "Student", column 'ID'.

I tried to check if there was any existing constraint with the same name. But I did not get any. Still I tried to drop the constraint. But then it gave the error:

> CHK_Student_ID_LENGTH is not a constraint.

But still add constraint statement gives error saying it already exists. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please check the tag summaries for [tag:mysql] and [tag:sql-server] and work out which one actually applies to your question. They're two *separate* products.

Comment: The error message comes from an ms sql server, not from mysql! Pls pay attention how you tag your question, otherwise it can mislead others and cause confusion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is a little badly worded, but isn't saying what you think it's saying.

It's *not* saying that there's already a constraint with the same name. It's saying that the constraint is being violated. That means that there is data already in the table that doesn't meet the requirements of the **new** constraint you're trying to introduce.

You *could* use the [`NOCHECK` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments) to create the constraint whilst allowing existing data to violate it. But this is frequently the wrong thing to do. It is usually more sensible to fix the existing data.

Specifying `NOCHECK` means that the constraint can't be used by the optimizer to eliminate redundant actions that the logic of the constraint would preclude.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some records in Your table that conflict with that new constraint.

Just find them and UPDATE/DELETE before adding a contraint.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Student 
WHERE LEN([ID]) between 12 and 14
```

Or try to add that constraint without checking existing values using `WITH NOCHECK`

```sql
ALTER TABLE Student WITH NOCHECK
ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_Student_ID_LENGTH CHECK (LEN([ID]) between 12 and 14);
```

**Tip:** In migration files I usually add this before adding a new constraint:

```sql
IF OBJECT_ID('CHK_Student_ID_LENGTH') IS NOT NULL
ALTER TABLE Student DROP CONSTRAINT CHK_Student_ID_LENGTH

IF OBJECT_ID('CHK_Student_ID_LENGTH') IS NULL
ALTER TABLE Student ADD CONSTRAINT ...
```

More about `ALTER TABLE` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15